# Why does my code's output go wrong at the end?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, g++

Today I have tried setting up vscode for c++ compiling and after compiling a simple cpp program I saw that the output is wrong and i have no idea why.

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/iLSVHW7T

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x[3],i,n;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    cin>>x[i];
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<x[i]<<" ";
}
```

[image: This image shows what is going wrong.]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You shouldn't put 4 items in an array of size 3.

Comment: @tkausl this is only the short answer

Comment: @tkausl but a vector starts with the position 0? when compiling on cpp.sh or visual studio ide it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `<=` used in the for loops. The first element of an array in C++ and C is indexed with 0 so `i` must be smaller than `n` to avoid an overflow.

In your code all elements from 0 to 3 are read. But the maximum amount of elements for this array is 2, so you read one more element that hasn't a real value.

So replace the `<=` with an `<`.

Comment: i don't think that's the problem?
i have change x[3] to x[4] and with the following input it works as it should:
input :

`4
1 2 3 4 5`
output :
`1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: @vanillaxqz really? Are you sure this isn't just a coincidence?